# Texture paint on animated cloths

Tags: texture-painting, cloth-simulation

i'm trying to figure this out for a while...
I want to texture paint 3 animated objects plus background in **one go** with the option to keep animate them after painting (just like spray painting irl)[image]

presumably I would need all these objects to be joined? any ideas? I have managed to do it with one cloth and a background

[image]

but now I want to do it w/ 3 objects.
Thank you!